# Why javers snapshot table sequence is multiplied by 100

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

We are using Spring data AuditAware with customization to save audit data in our tables. Recently we are building a new micro service we thought of exploring other alternative solutions.
And we found out Javers as a potential fit.

The integration with spring boot is seemless and auditing is done quite good.
But one concern is in the jv_snapshot table, the pk sequence is multiplied by 100. I have seen the source code, this is deliberately added for only this table. Is there any particular reason to do so?
My concern is we are expecting pretty big volume of data, what if the id column reaches the maximum big int value.
Please can any one let me know what is thought process behind this?

Comment: Is there any way to by-pass this may be a environment setting in yml file? So that the ids are created sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for better performance, in order to reduce the number of `nextval` statements being called. Don't worry about max int. For example, on MySQl, BIGINT has max= 2^63 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).